# Please wait 20 minutes for your entire balance to become spendable

Tags: unlocked-balance

I keep receiving a message that shows my Monero balance, but spendable balance is zero. The prompt reads "Please wait 20 minutes for your entire balance to become spendable". It has been over an hour. What should I do?

Answer (score 4):

Any transaction (XMR) received has to be 10 blocks old before becoming spendable.

New blocks are mined roughly every 2 minutes, so roughly 20 minutes.

If the monerod/node you are connected to is not fully synced, your balance will not become spendable until the node is synced past your transactions block + 10.

Same problem, if your wallet is having problems syncing from whatever node you are connected to.

Comment: But why e.g. Bitcoin doesn't have such limitation?

Comment: @Monsignor One reason is to avoid your incoming transaction does not get orphaned by a chain reorg.There are probably other reasons, but I don't remember. https://web.getmonero.org/library/ might have more answers.